# Mechanize - Submit form without click on submit button

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanize

Using Mechanize I fill a fom and I want to submit it without clicking on the submit button

```
<formulaire POST https://WWW/YYY/XXX.php application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(type=traitement) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(uid=zzzzz) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(no_tt=1) (readonly)>
  <SelectControl(ch_ee=[1;2])>
  <SubmitControl(bouton_m=ttttt) (readonly)>
  <SubmitControl(bouton_m=uuuuu) (readonly)>>
```

In fact the submitting is achieve using `onchange`function for the `ch_ee` form and it calls a `submit` function in JS: `this.document.formulaire.submit()`. I want to do the same thing, i.e. submitting the form without clicking on any `SubmitControl` button (this button allows to quit the website) but just by submitting using POST.

Comment: Well what you can do is that you can add a keypress, so that when you hit enter you submit it

Comment: @Nikki Something like `https://WWW/YYY/XXX.php&....&che_ee=1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this issue was to disable the two `SubmitControl` using the following syntax:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
for control in br.form.controls:
    if control.type == "submit":
        control.disabled = True
resp=br.submit()
```

The line `control.disabled=True` enables you to disable the two submit button (with `label=submit`)